# Run an .exe file with 1 input parameter from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, system, dos, exe, input-parameters

I have an .exe file developed in C# that is called by Matlab.

`DirPath = '\\MYSERVER\PARENT_DIR\CHILD DIR\'`

The old version of my command worked right

**without input parameter:**  `system( fullfile([DirPath 'NameOfExe']) )`

The new version which requires an input parameter is failing.  Can you please help me fix it?
I have tried many versions but the error is always:
**'\MYSERVER\PARENT_DIR\CHILD' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

**With input parameter, FAIL:**

```
strcommand = [  '''' fullfile([DirPath 'NameOfExe' ]) ' ' inputparameter '''' ];
eval(['[a,b]=system(' strcommand ')'])`
```

Correct usage when using CMD:
(say `I:` is my mapped drive to `MYSERVER`, & `inputparameter` is a path)

```
myroot:> cd I:
I:>cd PARENT_DIR\CHILD
I:\PARENT_DIR\CHILD>NameOfExe "inputparameter"
```

Comment: You can't have whitespace characters in the pathname.

Comment: @Dan is there a way to overwrite them? Like in Linux..using /

Comment: I am so sorry, I don't know! :(

Comment: Can you show what `strcommand` looks like when evaluated?